# Kendo UI (ASP.NET/Javascript) - newline or linebreak in string not displaying in tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-tooltip

I am creating a pie chart and one of the dataItem fields is a string in the following format:

"Hello\nWorld"

I am displaying it in my tooltip and it shows up as such: "Hello World". Ignoring my newline

I want it to show up as: 

"Hello
World"

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

I have got a reply from Kendo support:

```
  tooltip: {
    visible: true,
    template: "#= dataItem.Item.replace(/\\n/g, '<br/>') #"
  }
```

It works.

Comment: Tip : to use this in regular JS, just remove the extra \ before n.